# How to remove X-Powered-By: ARR/3.0 from IIS Web Farm?

Tags: iis, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I am asked to remove all `powered-by` response headers from an `IIS/ARR` hosted website. As always I followed the instructions from [this  article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/remove-unwanted-http-response-headers/ba-p/369710). I applied the required registry configuration , this is the only option worked for me before. The other options does not seem to be a solution for me because the second option is deprecated and the third option does not completely remove the header. I used this solution (Using the Registry key) successfully in the past on other IIS based websites but now it is not working in this case.Any Idea about how can I debug the problem or another potential solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about a single `ARR/3.0` header or all the headers? Keep in mind Stack Overflow welcomes specific questions, not as a whole, and each header does require a different setting.

Comment: @LexLi the question is crystal clear. I specifically mean X-Powered-By: ARR/3.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find 2 "X-powered-By" headers if you use the arr.

One is `X-powered-By: ASP.NET` .To disable this, remove it from Response Headers module from both arr server , back-end server ,server level and website level.

[image]

Second is `X-powered-by: ARR/3.0` .To disable this ,open the `arr_scheme.xml` file in ARR server.

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\Schema\arr_schema.xml
```

[image]

Find this attribute `arrResponseHeader` and change the defaultValue to `false`.

[image]

Save to file and restart the server, all "X-powered-by" header disappear.

This is test result:

[image]

Comment: Unbelievable! It just worked. Thank you for your detailed answer. I really wonder why this should not be mentioned in documentation?

Comment: That document does not contain the case of arr.

Comment: For others wondering, just make sure to change all `arrResponseHeader` to `false`, there might be more than one

Comment: Well doing as suggetsed removes the header but now image resources on my website does not load correctly. Response is  200 OK. Any idea why ?

Comment: I was unable to edit the file because of being in the system32 directory and locked by the Administrator. However, the following solution worked for me
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'
  -filter "system.webServer/proxy"
  -name "arrResponseHeader"
  -value "False"

https://get-note.net/2018/12/27/disable-iis-server-headers/